# python separate file by extension and save into folder accordingly

Tags: python, django

i am getting the filename as instance and files are easily saved into the db no issue at all. but i need to check the file extension and saving the files into separately like this

I expected the output like this
separate file extension and saved accordingly

```
phots
 image1.jpg
 image2.jpg
text
 text1.txt
 text2.txt
```

This is my model class

```
class Album(models.Model):
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    name_content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And Function is here

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    upload_dir = os.path.join('uploads', 'resource')
    return os.path.join(upload_dir, filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the extension using `splitext`:

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    ext = ext.lstrip(".")                          # Remove leading dot
    if ext in ("jpg", "jpeg", "png"):
        subdir = "phots"
    elif ext in ("txt", "asc"):
        subdir = "text"
    else:
        subdir = extension
    upload_dir = os.path.join('uploads', 'resource', subdir)
    return os.path.join(upload_dir, filename)
```

Comment: see if i want to add timestamp to the uploaded file like (timestamp)image.jpg . How to do that ?

Comment: just use `os.path.join(upload_dir, str(datetime.datetime.now()) + filename)`

Comment: Or use formatted strings `os.path.join(upload_dir, "{:%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S} {}".format(datetime.datetime.now(), filename))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .endswith functionality and check

```
    if filename.endswith("jpg") or silename.endswith("jpeg"):
         subdir = "phots"
    elif filename.endswith("txt") or filename.endswith("asc"):
         subdir = "docs"
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a map as opposed to if/else statements as its more extensible.

```
dir_map = {".jpg"  : "photos",
           ".jpeg" : "photos",
           ".png"  : "photos",
           ".txt"  : "text",
           ".asc"  : "text"
          }
_, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
subdir = dir_map.get(ext, "other")
return os.path.join("uploads", "resource", dir_map.get(ext, "other"), filename)
```